# Laravel Subdomain routing, routes undefined inside Route Domain Group

Tags: laravel

I am trying to move all my routes inside a subdomain routes group. When I put routes inside subdomain group, issues arise. Routes become undefined. This way works.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('profile', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit']);
    Route::put('profile', ['as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update']);
    
});
```

This way does not work. Links generated with route helper generates undefined errror,  `href="{{ route('profile.edit') }}"`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::domain('{username}.'.env('SESSION_DOMAIN'))->group(function () {

        Route::get('dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
        Route::get('profile', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit']);
        Route::put('profile', ['as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update']);

    });
});
```

I thought I came up with a solution when I used url helper, `href="{{ url('profile.edit') }}"` , but a new problem started. Links to other pages were fine, but form submission actions generated a error

> Missing required parameters

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your route requires the subdomain parameter. `{username}` needs to be passed with your route but you are not passing anything. thus the missing required parameters error comes. you have to call a route like

```
href="{{ route('profile.edit', 'subdomain_name') }}"
```

or if you have a fixed subdomain then just remove `{username}` from your route definition and use the exact sub domain.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::domain('subdomain_name.'.env('SESSION_DOMAIN'))->group(function () {

        Route::get('dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
        Route::get('profile', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit']);
        Route::put('profile', ['as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update']);

    });
});
```